# unable to change the security properties on PDF file to password protect it

Tags: security, pdf, passwords, adobe-acrobat

I have PDF file I scanned. I am unable to change the security setting to add password it it.

Here is link how to password protect it and also the screenshot for the gray'ed out security propety.

I have already tried. File Save As PDF and it still didn't work.

[Guide To add password.](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/acrobat-x-tips-tricks/how-do-i-password-protect-a-document/)

[image]

Comment: use save as and create a new copy.

Comment: I have already done that, it didn't work.

Comment: If you tried that.  You should mention that you tried it in the question itself.  Because my initial thought was that the method you used to create the .PDF was limited in some capacity.

Comment: I am sorry, I will do that.

Comment: A very stupid question: are you in Acrobat or in Reader (XI)?

Answer (score 1):

Print it to another PDF. Open that PDF and then add the security you want.

Comment: I don't see option to print to PDF.

Comment: Depending on the Windows version, Linux version, etc. You can also install some "pdf printer" (google it and you'll find a lot of softwares that are installed and act like a printer, so you'll be able to print to PDF).

Answer (score 0):

If you are really in Acrobat (see comment above), check the settings for PDF/A viewing mode. You find that in the Documents tab of the Preferences: View Documents in PDF/A mode, and set it to Never. As you say they are scanned, it is possible that the scan software creates (or pretends to create) PDF/A documents.